# Converting qsort function to std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I currently have this comparator function that sorts a custom struct using qsort, and I want to port it to std::sort, but it seems like it needs to return a bool value instead of -1, 0 and 1, how would I rewrite it?

```
int tsort = 1, sorta = 1;

static auto titleSort(const void *c1, const void *c2) -> int {
    switch (tsort) {
        case 0:
            return ((Title *) c1)->listID - ((Title *) c2)->listID;

        case 1:
            return strcmp(((Title *) c1)->shortName, ((Title *) c2)->shortName) * sorta;

        case 2:
            if (((Title *) c1)->isTitleOnUSB == ((Title *) c2)->isTitleOnUSB)
                return 0;
            if (((Title *) c1)->isTitleOnUSB)
                return -1 * sorta;
            if (((Title *) c2)->isTitleOnUSB)
                return 1 * sorta;
            return 0;

        case 3:
            if (((Title *) c1)->isTitleOnUSB && !((Title *) c2)->isTitleOnUSB)
                return -1 * sorta;
            if (!((Title *) c1)->isTitleOnUSB && ((Title *) c2)->isTitleOnUSB)
                return 1 * sorta;

            return strcmp(((Title *) c1)->shortName, ((Title *) c2)->shortName) * sorta;

        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return true if the first argument is less than the second. This is equivalent to mapping "<0" to true and everything else to false.

Comment: First thing you'd do is declare the arguments `Title * c1, Title * c2` and throw away the casts

Comment: where are `tsort` and `sorta` defined?

Comment: you also need to consider that there are stricter requirements for a comparator used with `std::sort` compared to the one for `qsort`. For `std::sort` you need a strict weak ordering.

Comment: For a Q&D solution, return `titleSort(...) < 0`

Comment: Maybe you should forget about the qsort() code and think of the sorting criteria on a high-level.  For example, if the ID's are sorted in ascending order, then that is the 3 argument `std::sort` call with a lambda that returns `true` if the first id is < the second id.  Looking back at qsort() code that would look very dissimilar to `std::sort` may just add to the confusion.

Comment: ... And for better performance (probably), listen to what @PaulMcKenzie is saying and use a lambda (or better still, a variety of lambdas, to avoid casing out on `tsort`), the point being that the more the compiler knows about your comparator - and the simpler it is - then the more likely it is to be able to inline the code.

Comment: *but it seems like it needs to return a bool value instead of -1, 0 and 1* -- That's basically the point being made.   This looks like a case of trying to retrofit old code by plunking it down into the new paradigm while holding onto the "old code" way of doing things.  Better to just figure out what the old code is doing, throw away the old code, and implement the new code using the idioms that the new code would use.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I second this sentiment. If you’re afraid to delete code, you’re also probably afraid to touch it, which means it gets zero maintenance and will only grow more stale over time. I pray it has unit tests, but doubt it.

Comment: Use separate functions and pass the one you want explicitly instead of choosing between them with a mess of global state.

Comment: Is changing `Title` so it has `std::string` members instead of `char*` (or `char[]`) an option?

Comment: @OP Please describe in words (i.e., the high-level goal) the sort for option `2` and `3`  is supposed to denote.  It isn't clear from the code you posted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I assume that `isTitleOnUSB` is a `bool` (and `sorta` is for direction (ascending or descending order)). and `3` is to compare on 2 fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, get rid of `int tsort = 1, sorta = 1;`

and use directly the appropriate method.

The dispatch, if needed, can be done with something like (C++20):

```
void sortTitle(std::vector<Title>& title, int tsort = 1, sorta = 1)
{
    switch (tsort)
    {
        case 0:
            std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::less{}, &Title::listID); break;
        case 1: {
            const auto proj = [](const Title& title){
                return std::string_view(title.shortName);
            };
            if (sorta == 1) {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::less{}, proj);
            } else {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::greater{}, proj);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            if (sorta == 1) {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::less{}, &Title::isTitleOnUSB);
            } else {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::greater{}, &Title::isTitleOnUSB);
            }
            break;
        case 3: {
            const auto proj = [](const Title& title){
                return std::make_tuple(title.isTitleOnUSB,
                                       std::string_view(title.shortName));
            };
            if (sorta == 1) {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::less{}, proj);
            } else {
                std::ranges::sort(titles, std::ranges::greater{}, proj);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Projections - clever and surprisingly clean.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in a comment, the simple, quick, and dirty solution is

```
std::sort(first,last, [](const auto& a,const auto& b) { 
          return titleSort(&a,&b) < 0; 
});
```

Because the comparator for `std::sort` should return `true` when `a < b` and `false` otherwise. When `a < b` then `titleSort` returns `-1` and `0` or `1` otherwise. Hence you want to map `1` to `true` and `0` and `1` to `false`, and `< 0` does that.

You also need to consider that the comparator for `std::sort` must conform to the named requirement [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). Typical comparisons do that, but when they don't then using them with `std::sort` is undefined. I didn't find similar requirement for `qsort`.

Answer (score 0):

The [pragmatic approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72688544/7582247) has a lot of upsides. You don't need to change much for example.

However, the old `titleSort` did a lot of runtime checking of the `tsort` and `sorta` values. It would be better if the runtime values could be checked one time only (in runtime).

You could create a functor template that you instantiate with `tsort` and `sorta` as template parameters. If you'd like to keep all the logic in one place as before, you'd use *constexpr-if* to make the selection:

```cpp
enum class tsort_t { zero, one, two, three };

template <tsort_t tsort, bool sorta = false>
struct titleSorter {
    bool operator()(const Title& a, const Title& b) const {
        if constexpr (tsort == tsort_t::zero) {
            return b.listID < a.listID;

        } else if constexpr (tsort == tsort_t::one) {
            return std::strcmp(a.shortName, b.shortName) < 0;

        } else if constexpr (tsort == tsort_t::two) {
            if (a.isTitleOnUSB == b.isTitleOnUSB) return false;
            if constexpr (sorta) {
                return a.isTitleOnUSB;
            } else {
                return b.isTitleOnUSB;
            }
        } else if constexpr (tsort == tsort_t::three) {
            if (a.isTitleOnUSB != b.isTitleOnUSB) {
                if constexpr (sorta) {
                    return a.isTitleOnUSB;
                } else {
                    return b.isTitleOnUSB;
                }
            } else {
                return strcmp(a.shortName, b.shortName) < 0;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

<sup>Disclaimer: I *may* have made some mistakes when converting the logic, but I think it's ok - double check it</sup>

And for checking the runtime values of `tsort` and `sorta`, you'd add a frontend which instantiates the proper `titleSorter`:

```cpp
template <class It>
void titleSort(It first, It last, int tsort, int sorta) {
    switch (tsort) {
        case 0:
            std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::zero>{});
            break;
        case 1:
            if (sorta == 1)
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::one, true>{});
            else
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::one>{});
            break;
        case 2:
            if (sorta == 1)
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::two, true>{});
            else
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::two>{});
            break;
        case 3:
            if (sorta == 1)
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::three, true>{});
            else
                std::sort(first, last, titleSorter<tsort_t::three>{});
            break;
        default:
            throw std::runtime_error("erroneous tsort algorithm selected");
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7TKc5eej1)

Note: I would also consider changing `shortName` to being a `std::string`.